# How to enlarge tree timeout in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco

In Umbraco (7.1.6) I have some media folders with a lot of content. Some folders don't expand. I think this has something to do with the amount of content. The error occurs when trying to access:

`umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoTrees/MediaTree/GetNodes?id=52576&application=media&tree=&isDialog=false`

Is there a way to enlarge the timeout. The error seems to be there after 30 seconds.

Comment: If you open up the Chrome web dev tools and look in the network tab, what does the request return? Is there an associated error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit late with a reply but might help someone..

The issue you are experiencing is related to SQL command that is timing out before it could complete loading the content. As of Umbraco v 7.4.0 the timeout can be adjusted by adding "Connection Timeout = seconds" to the connection string in web.config where you specify the number of seconds.

One way to solve this without having to upgrade Umbraco is to download source code of the version of Umbraco that you are running and hard-code the timeout value and make a custom build of Umbraco.Core.dll file as specified in this post.. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/umbraco-dev/oP6S28N9ynw

Secondly, you can also make a custom build of Umbraco.Core.dll, making changes to UmbracoDatabase.cs using https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/pull/1097/files
This way you will be able to adjust the timeout value directly from web.config without having to upgrade Umbraco. Since this change is available form version 7.4.0 you will not loose changes that you've done if an Umbraco upgrade is required in the future.

If you require any clarification, please let me know.